# Automatic Magento Price Update

Tags: magento-1.9, price, tax

we have entered the price already. Now we have received our VAT Tax rate and we need the prices on frontend product pages to show the new OLD RATE + VAT total figure.

But it doesnt happen that way. Im not able to find that settings too.
Am I missing something ?

Comment: what have you done so far? have you implemented your tax rate? is it working properly?

Comment: Yes everything works perfect. Is there a way I can bulk update all prices ?

Comment: did you enter prices in the backend including or excluding VAT?